# Is there a way to control the Progress bar on Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

Is there a way - JavaScript/CSS/HTML to control the progress bar of the chrome app from a website?

I have built a web app which loads multiple ads inside it. The progress bar loads once for each app. Since there are multiple ads, consequently, the progress bar flickers multiple times. How do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the loading indicator. Further there is no public documentation as to how it works currently. It is some pretty complicated logic on how it is dictated whether it should be shown or not.